# How to handle frame in page object model

Tags: java, selenium

Can you please tell me how to handle frames in page object model??

While trying with linear script the same works but when i moved the same to page object model then the script fails.

Currently in my framework below is the process i followed:

1. Made `switchTo()` as a generic function and placed in the generic library.
2. In pages where there needs a control to be moved to the required frame I've called `switchTo()` method of the generic library.
3. Next after passing the control to frame I've performed action in the required web element.(The thing is it is unable to find the particular object)

Can anyone tell me the possible issue ?

Common Library:

```
public void switchToFrame(int frame)
    {
        try
        {
            Driver.driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
            System.out.println("Navigated to frame with name " + frame);
        }
        catch (NoSuchFrameException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to locate frame with id " + frame + e.getStackTrace());
        }
}
```

pages :

```
public void createticket(String interactionTitle,String interactionDesc,String category,String originText,String priorityText,String impactText) throws InterruptedException
    {
        switchToFrame(1);
        System.out.println("Navigated to Frame");
        waitForIdPresent("X49");
        titleEdt.sendKeys(interactionTitle);//unable to enter here
        descEdt.sendKeys(interactionDesc);
        dropDown(origipublic void createInteraction(String interactionTitle,String interactionDesc,String category,String originText,String priorityText,String impactText) throws InterruptedException
    {
        switchToFrame(1);
        System.out.println("Navigated to Frame");
        waitForIdPresent("X49");
        Driver.driver.findElement(By.id("X49")).sendKeys(interactionTitle);
        descEdt.sendKeys(interactionDesc);
        dropDown(originDropDown, originText);
}
```

Test script :

```
@Test
    public void createTestTicket() throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException, InterruptedException{

        homePage.getBtn().click();
        homePage.getLnk().click();
        interactionDetails.createTicket("test ticket","test ticket","incident","CALL","P1 / <1hour","1 - Enterprise");
    }
```

Comment: Can you share `waitForIdPresent()` ? maybe the problem is there.

Comment: public void waitForIdPresent(String wbId)
 {
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.driver,20);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.name(wbId)));  
 }

Comment: Upon working in a linear fashion with Thread.Sleep it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think, waitForIdPresent("id") is throwing the error in your case. 
In the comment you have provided, you

```
public void waitForIdPresent(String wbId)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.name(wbId)));   ‌
}
```

Change By.name to By.id in this.